# How to remove Query string from URL, but take action using Query string

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I have following link:

```
http://foo.com/index.php?action_skin_change=yes&skin_name=mynewskin
```

And I want to take corresponding actions in PHP (skin change), but as result I want to see in address bar following URL:

```
http://foo.com
```

Is it possible to do this ONLY with .htaccess, or I need to call 301 redirect in PHP after skin change? Thanks advance!

Comment: it's not possible unless you send a POST request. Possible would be `http://foo.com/action_skin_change/mynewskin`, but that's not what you like, right?

Comment: _"after skin change"_ - how do you send the skin change? From a form, a link, ..?

Comment: @Jeff I am using GET query for this

Comment: And result http://foo.com/action_skin_change/mynewskin is not that I want, sorry.

Comment: If you can change it to a POST (form?) you won't see the sent parameters in the url.

Comment: Ok, many thanks. But I tried to go away from POST query, as there an issue in some browsers with refresh warning for pages that received via POST.

Comment: Changing a skin should not result in a page refresh. Sounds like you actually have a separate and perhaps related problem.